# Pattern matching with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a list of dictionary words in my input file, and I'm trying to pattern match for a word that has all the vowels (a,e,i,o,u) that appear in the word in that order. They do not have to be right next to each other. Right now, this is the code I have:

```
open(INFILE, "words.txt") or die "Can't open word.txt: $!";
while(<INFILE>){
    $word = <INFILE>;
    if($word =~ /[a-z][a-zA-Z]*a[a-zA-Z]*e[a-zA-Z]*i[a-zA-Z]*o[a-zA-Z]*u[a-zA-Z]*/){
        print $word;
    }
}
close(INFILE);
```

But I return no words even though I know there is a word in my input with this pattern. Can I get an explanation why? This is for homework.

EDIT: the first letter has to be lowercase and all vowels must be lowercase. Also, I can't have repeats when searching for the aeiou pattern.

EDIT2: An example of words that would match is `abstemiousness`, `aAbstemiousness` and `badetikojuw.` Examples that don't match are `ambeeiou` (repeat of e before it found the full pattern of aeiou), `0abstemiousness` (non-letter 0), `Taeiou` (starts with capital letter), `baEstmious` (no lower case `e` found).

Comment: Just some advice, you should use the three argument open. `open (my $infile, "<", "words.txt")`, and either set `my $word` in the `while` loop or use the default `$_` variable inside.  I prefer `while(my $word = <$infile>)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! however, can you please explain what the "<" does?

Comment: That just says "Open this file for reading".  Here is a good link on why this is considered best practice for Perl 5.6 and on. https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1582932&seqNum=2

Comment: Please provide some examples of words that should match and words that should not. The requirements are not entirely clear. For example, which of the following words should match: aeiou eiouaeiou aeAAiou Baeiou aeBBiou aeiouBB aeeiou aebeiou

Comment: I just added some examples. Let me know if it's still unclear what matches and what doesn't.

Comment: Okay, it's alright I got my program to work! Thank you!

Comment: 1. You reading one line into $_ then another into $word, so you're skipping every second word.

Comment: 2. You made it so there has to be a letter before the first 'a'.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
a.*e.*i.*o.*u
```

The `.*` matches zero or more characters in between, so writing it that way assures that the vowels are in order.  This also assumes that there is only one word per line, which seems to be the case.

EDIT:

Alternative:

```
a\w*e\w*i\w*o\w*u
```

Alternative without `_` and digits:

```
a[a-z]*e[a-z]*i[a-z]*o[a-z]*u
```

Alternative without duplicate vowels in-a-row:

```
a[b-df-hj-np-tv-z] #repeat
```

Comment: While this is an easy and simple solution, I don't want to result to print if there is a character other than a letter in my word. I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

You're skipping half of your input.

Each occurrence of  will read a line; you're calling it twice. The first time assigns the results to $_ (the default pronoun), which is discarded.

Try putting

```
     while (my $word = <INFILE>)
```

to avoid discarding every other line of input.

Answer (score 1):

You are excluding the case where there is only 1 `a` and it appears at the beginning. And note that the vowels are case-sensitive while other characters are not.

Since you are not doing an anchored match (match the whole input string, instead of allowing a match to start and end arbitrarily in the middle of the input string), you can write it like this:

```
/[Aa][a-zA-Z]*[Ee][a-zA-Z]*[Ii][a-zA-Z]*[Oo][a-zA-Z]*[Uu]/
```

Or you can turn on the case-insensitive flag `i`:

```
/a[a-z]*e[a-z]*i[a-z]*o[a-z]*u/i
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Lp5EbK)

**The only assumption that the answer above makes is that the rest of the words before `a` and after `u` are English letter.**

If you want to make sure the whole string only contains of English letters, and has the pattern, you need an anchored match:

```
/^[a-z]*a[a-z]*e[a-z]*i[a-z]*o[a-z]*u[a-z]*$/i
```

This is the strictest form, with validation on all the characters in the word, and disallows `@#$garblesdifdoup@#` from matching.

Comment: Hi, there were some important requirements that I missed out on, can you please see my post again? I'm not sure how to solve this problem now since the pattern may or may not contain an a in the beginning. I believe your solution always assumes there is an a in the beginning.

Comment: @user1831442: I don't make such assumption.

Comment: Hmm, could you please explain? If you put an `a` in front doesn't that mean the first character in the word has to be an a? And what about after the `u`? What if there are letters after the u?

Comment: @user1831442: Unanchored match can start and end in the middle of the string. So as long as you find a substring (contiguous sequence) that matches the regex, then it is fine. It has the assumption that you don't care about the part before `a` and after `u`. I also give the other way, where you do anchored match (need the whole string to match the whole regex). This allows you to do a strict validation on the whole word + check for the pattern of vowels